# How to check whether a directory is readable or writable?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want a way to know whether a directory/folder is readable or writable. I searched for a direct way to do that by a function or like that but I didn't find it.

I tried to do it indirectly as follow:

Is readable:

```
WIN32_FIND_DATAA dirData;
HANDLE hDir;
hDir = FindFirstFile("C:\\folder", &dirData);
if (hDir == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return false;
return true;
```

Is writable:

```
DWORD attr = GetFileAttributes(m_dirPath);
if (attr != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES && attr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY)
    return false;
return true;
```

- The first code is an indirect way to know whether a directory
  readable but it is not efficient because when the directory is empty
  it returns 0 which is not readable.
- The second code to check whether a directory is writable but it
  always returns 1 which is writable although I have changed the
  directory permission to read-only.

**Is there a direct or indirect way to know whether a directory is readable or writable?**

Comment: The `stat` function gives permissions.

Comment: You need to check for `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES`.

Comment: @user207421: still, always returns 1 (writable).

Comment: 99.9% of the time, the correct test is to try to open a file for read or write, and handle the error if it doesn't work. Look Before You Leap (LBYL) solutions are inherently race-prone; even if the test says you can do it, you might *not* be able to do it when you actually try to open the file, so you end up either failing hard, or having to protect against the race by doing all the things your pre-test was intended to protect you from. EAFP (easier to ask forgiveness than seek permission) solutions actually do the thing you need to do, and handle the errors just once (without races).

Comment: In the first code, when `FindFirstFile()` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, use `GetLastError()` to differentiate between a real error vs no files being found.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Your trick `GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` works well, Thank you.

Comment: @LionKing I was thinking more of checking for `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, anything else is an error. But whatever works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want a way to know whether a directory/folder is readable or
>   writable.

Directly to try to open the directory with read/write access permission via [`CreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) API:

```
HANDLE tDir = CreateFile(L"D:\\testNew", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);
if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == tDir)
    printf("Open directory failed with error %d \n", GetLastError());
else
    printf("Readable. \n");

tDir = CreateFile(L"D:\\testNew", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);
if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == tDir)
    printf("Open directory failed with error %d \n", GetLastError());
else
    printf("Writable. \n");
```

If it is a read-only directory you will receive access denied error when you open it with `GENERIC_WRITE`.

**For read-only**, the directory maybe set to deny current user to write, however it is not a read-only directory. At this time you will get "This directory is not read-only" result but you still can't write.

[image]

**Update:**

As @RaymondChen pointed out, you can confirm the desired access right to a directory more accurately using [file access rights constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-access-rights-constants). Take `FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY` as an example:

```
tDir = CreateFile(L"D:\\testNew", FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);
if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == tDir)
    printf("Open directory failed with error %d \n", GetLastError());
else
    printf("Has right to list the contents of the directory.\n");
```

Comment: The security on directories is more fine grained than just read and write. If you want to know if you can list the contents of the directory, you want FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY. If you want to know if you can create files, then check for FILE_ADD_FILE. If you want to know if you can create subdirectories, use FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY. [The full list is in msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-access-rights-constants).

Comment: The difference between `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` and `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` or the other flags (Why that flag in particular)?

Comment: @LionKing [**Flags (`FILE_FLAG_*`)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/ns-fileapi-createfile2_extended_parameters) for control of file or device caching behavior, access modes, and other special-purpose flags. [**File attributes (`FILE_ATTRIBUTE_*`)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-attribute-constants) are metadata values stored by the file system on disk and are used by the system and are available to developers via various file I/O APIs.